# Can I plot a VOTable in Python with a Specified Range?

Tags: python, astropy

I have a VOTable file (from GAIA) with ~47,000 points. I am able to use astropy.io.votable to parse the table and read all the values for specific columns (particularly: ra, dec, parallax, magnitude, and color). I have been able to create plots including all of the points in the table, but now I want to zoom in on a certain RA and Dec range and plot only the CMD of the points within that range.

All of the points are currently read with this code:

```
from astropy.io.votable import parse
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from astropy.io.votable import parse_single_table

table = parse_single_table("votables/star.vot")
ra = table.array['ra']
dec = table.array['dec']
gmag = table.array['phot_g_mean_mag']
parallax = table.array['parallax']
g_rp = table.array['g_rp']

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2)
im1 = ax1.scatter(dec, ra, s=0.2, c=parallax, cmap='gray')
im2 = ax2.scatter(g_rp, gmag, s=0.4, c=parallax, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

(I did cut out some of the code for plotting since it is not important for the question). The only "fix" I've reliably tried for this is just doing another GAIA search with the range of RA and DEC I wanted to zoom in on, but it is obviously a very unreliable and barbaric workaround. I am also working on Python 3.6 so I cannot use astroquery to hasten the search. Is there a way to simply select a range of RA (85.1 to 85.7) and Dec (-2.5 to -1.1) from the full table and extract/plot the corresponding gmag/parallax/g_rp/etc. values?

Edit: Added a sample ADQL to input in https://gea.esac.esa.int/archive/ search function to generate similar .vot file as used here.

> Blockquote
> SELECT TOP 2000 gaia_source.source_id,gaia_source.ra,gaia_source.dec,gaia_source.parallax,gaia_source.pmra,gaia_source.pmdec,gaia_source.ruwe,gaia_source.phot_g_mean_mag,gaia_source.bp_rp,gaia_source.g_rp,gaia_source.radial_velocity,gaia_source.phot_variable_flag,gaia_source.non_single_star,gaia_source.has_xp_continuous,gaia_source.has_xp_sampled,gaia_source.has_rvs,gaia_source.has_epoch_photometry,gaia_source.has_epoch_rv,gaia_source.has_mcmc_gspphot,gaia_source.has_mcmc_msc,gaia_source.teff_gspphot,gaia_source.logg_gspphot,gaia_source.mh_gspphot,gaia_source.distance_gspphot,gaia_source.azero_gspphot,gaia_source.ag_gspphot,gaia_source.ebpminrp_gspphot
> FROM gaiadr3.gaia_source
> WHERE
> CONTAINS(
> POINT('ICRS',gaiadr3.gaia_source.ra,gaiadr3.gaia_source.dec),
> CIRCLE(
> 'ICRS',
> COORD1(EPOCH_PROP_POS(84.68652242855,-2.60007866108,3.0400,4.6000,-.4000,29.9000,2000,2016.0)),
> COORD2(EPOCH_PROP_POS(84.68652242855,-2.60007866108,3.0400,4.6000,-.4000,29.9000,2000,2016.0)),
> 0.5)
> )=1  AND  (gaiadr3.gaia_source.parallax BETWEEN 1 AND 2 AND gaiadr3.gaia_source.g_rp<=2000 AND gaiadr3.gaia_source.phot_g_mean_mag>=14)
> Blockquote

Comment: Since we don't have the datafile, could you mention how best to obtain the data in `votables/star.vot`? That would answering your question.

Comment: @9769953  All of the data was downloaded from https://gea.esac.esa.int/archive/ . I have edited the question with a sample ADQL that you can put in the Search to generate a .vot similar (but much smaller) than the one I am using.

Answer (score 0):

Since this concerns just the one table, it is possible to convert the VO table to a single AstroPy table:

```
from astropy.io.votable import parse
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from astropy.io.votable import parse_single_table

table = parse_single_table("votables/star.vot").to_table()  # to_table() does the trick
```

Now we can filter this table by coordinates:

```
mask = (table['ra'] >= 85.1) & (table['ra'] <= 85.7) 
mask &= (table['dec'] >= -2.5) & (table['dec'] <= 1.1)
```

Note that this works, since there is no crossing of the RA = 0; otherwise, you'd have to use some of the coordinate utilities to query within an area.

With the above mask, the selection is then plotted in the same way as your code; just the table access is slightly different.

```
mtable = table[mask]
ra = mtable['ra']
dec = mtable['dec']
gmag = mtable['phot_g_mean_mag']
parallax = mtable['parallax']
g_rp = mtable['g_rp']

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2)
im1 = ax1.scatter(dec, ra, s=0.2, c=parallax, cmap='gray')
im2 = ax2.scatter(g_rp, gmag, s=0.4, c=parallax, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

[image: figure with subselection]

Which just shows 18 sources, which is the length of the masked table (i.e., `mask.sum() == 18`).